# Proper Chain of Commands to Maintain 3 Repos

Tags: git, github

I have a situation where I've concluded I need 3(really 4) Repos to maintain my work. I'm currently alternating working from home and working in the office. For this reason, I've setup a repo that both my work/home computers push and pull to/from. Then that "unified" repo gets pushed to the official repo.

Here's the breakdown:
Repo A Official

Repo B staging/unifying - this is needed for the scenario where I make changes at work that aren't ready for the Official but need to be pullable from my home computer so I can continue working.

Repo C/D local(2 of these, one home computer, one on work computer) - this holds my true working changes

I'm looking for the proper way(read: proper command/sync sequence) to maintain this setup. Currently I'm doing the steps below, and maybe they're correct, but I find that I keep having consistency issues.

Repo A -> Clone to Repo B

Repo B -> Clone to Repo C/D

Make changes to C or D, commit, push to B

Go to B, commit(do I need to do this to pickup the commit from C?), pull(from A before push), push to A

Please let me know if this is proper or if there's something more that needs to be done.
Thanks in advance and sorry if I'm using the wrong names for Git specific things.

Comment: Instead of multiple repos have you considered using multiple branches against the main repo , or against your fork of the repo. The link gives an overview of how this would work with your fork: https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/

Comment: @Mani Thanks for the response. I could see a fork possibly being a better method to solve my situation, but still, I'm unclear on the sequence of commands to make sure everything is kept in order(today I seem to have "lost" yet another commit). I read your link and I'm a bit confused about the process to push changes back up to the master. I fork, I clone the fork so I now have a local, I make changes, commit, push, changes are now in the fork, but then I send a pull request to push to master ?

Comment: That is correct, you would create a Pull request from a branch in your fork to the main repo.